# How to use system proxy in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

I can use requests lib to connect a website, cause using system proxy,
but when I use asyncio, cannot connect. So where to set  asyncio to use system proxy?

I use telethon lib (not aiohttp) which using python_socks/async_/asyncio to connect telegram, so should I change code of asyncio?

Comment: what is a system proxy? Did you use proxies like this in requests? ```proxies = {
   'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:8080',
   'https': 'http://secureproxy.example.com:8090',
}```

Comment: when I use  'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:8080' on requests lib to connect  telegram.org , status =200; And  when I use same proxy on asyncio to connect  telegram.org failed,  maybe my network  can't connect proxy, but when I use clash(system proxy software), work on requests lib, and dont work on asyncio, so I think requests used sysmtem proxy defaultly?

Comment: you should look at this, you can try to integrate this with your client https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/network.html

Comment: I tried all connection type, don't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.